# How can I use TinyMCE editor only for image uploading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, image-uploading, tinymce-plugins

I want to use TinyMCE editor only for image using also imagetools plugin to edit the image. Thus I need following options:

1. No editor field should be visible: only field like this(I can do the design ) [image: drag and drop files here to upload]
2. Then after selecting image : user can edit/resize/etcjust like used in TinyMCE editor using imagetools plugin .

Actually How can I override TinyMCE editor and use ?

If there is any other work around beside TinyMCE or mentioned above Please reply with it also.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get a solution?